# sending Images in peer to peer chat using Agora SDK in android

Tags: android, chat, agora.io, peer

**need demo example for Images sending for peer to peer**

```
 RtmRequestId requestId = new RtmRequestId();
```

mRtmClient.createImageMessageByUploading(fileName, requestId, new ResultCallback() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(RtmImageMessage rtmImageMessage) {

```
 }

 @Override
 public void onFailure(ErrorInfo errorInfo) {

 }
```

});

```
 private void isNetworkAvailableUploadGallImage(String profileImageString , byte[] bitmap) {
    Log.d("ImageUpload", profileImageString);


    if (!connD.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.internetUnAvailable), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {

        RtmRequestId requestId = new RtmRequestId();
        mRtmClient.createImageMessageByUploading(profileImageString, requestId, new ResultCallback<RtmImageMessage>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(RtmImageMessage rtmImageMessage) {
                media_id = rtmImageMessage.getMediaId();
                Log.d("byte array",""+bitmap);
                rtmImageMessage.setThumbnail(bitmap);
                mRtmClient.sendMessageToPeer(toProfID, rtmImageMessage, new SendMessageOptions(), new ResultCallback<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        runOnUiThread(() -> {

                            byte[] imageBytes = rtmImageMessage.getThumbnail();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sendMessageToPeer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.d("image send ", "" + imageBytes);
                            String str=new String(imageBytes);
                            massageList.add(new ChatItem(ChatItem.LayoutThree,"",str , dateTime, true));
                            chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        });

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(ErrorInfo errorInfo) {
                        Log.d("image send fail", errorInfo.toString()+errorInfo.getErrorDescription());

                    }
                });


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(ErrorInfo errorInfo) {
                Log.d("OnFalu", errorInfo.getErrorCode() + errorInfo.toString());
                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + errorInfo.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                });
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**when call this method **

```
 byte[] imageBytes = rtmImageMessage.getThumbnail();
```

*it return value is like byte array: [B@419089a*
**not in form of byte array need help**

Comment: You can refer to this sample code: https://github.com/AgoraIO/RTM/tree/master/Agora-RTM-Tutorial-Android

Comment: thank you its helpfull. solve my problem